# Why are there so many achamanams while ideally there should only be one?

Tags: vedas, rituals, mantras

So that anyone willing to do a Vedic ritual like a Puja or a Homam will have a standard and the same procedure to follow.

Right now, every region, every sampradaya have their own way of doing things which should not be the case in my opinion.

Is any such procedure mentioned in any of the 4 Vedas?

PS-Achamanam is the purification ritual which usually consists of sipping water three times associated with mantras in an effort to aptly purify oneself before doing a ritual like Puja etc.

Comment: Sandhyavandanam Achman is same for everybody, so as far as vedic achman is considered it is same for everyone(regardless of sect and philosophy).

Comment: @Yogi How can the Sandhya achamana  be the same given that there are N number of Sandhya vidhis followed by different Veda Shaka followers?..FOr ex-the Paipladin Shaka of Atharva Veda uses "Om Pranaya Swaha,Apanaya swaha ,Vyanaya Swaha "as their achamana mantra..and there r several others too..

Comment: Okay I think achyutaya namaha...etc is the standard vedic achman. I need to find out more about this because rigvedi and yajurvedi achman are same afaik.

Comment: I don't know which Shaka I belong to. But I am a Krishna Yajurvedi. Should I learn entire Krishna Yajur Veda?

Comment: @Parikshitha Yes u should at least learn that.